# Should a django's HttpResponse.content encoded in the charset specified by the Content-Type?

Tags: python, django

**Context**: django 1.3

My view is sending a HttpResponse with mimetype:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

When I invoke a GET:

```
>> from django.test.client import Client
>> client = Client()
>> resp = client.get('/stream/news/')
>> type(resp.content)
<type 'str'>
```

1. Is `resp.content` guaranteed to be encoded in `utf-8` ?